# How to find out direct URL address of a file?

Tags: firefox, download

For example here: http://www.nova-institut.de/bio/index.php?tpl=shoplist&id=&aid=&lng=en when you see »Free Download« or here: http://faostat3.fao.org/browse/F/*/E, you cannot get direct URLs to the files that are downloaded.

Is there any way to get a direct link when the site does not allow »copy link adress« which would lead to the direct file location?

Answer (score 1):

Some files may be generated dynamically & the file may not exist before the time you've requested. So a blunt & obvious way may be to actually download the file & note the URL from the address bar or get it from the downloaded file list provided by the browser. In Chrome, this list is shown by visiting the URL chrome://downloads/ and you can find the actual path of the file from there. Alternatively, you can open the browser Developer Tools (F12 keyboard shortcut) and look under the Network tab. Once the file download starts, you can find the complete path of the file in the list under Network tab.

In all the cases, you can stop the download soon after you copy the URL if you don't actually need the file.

Answer (score 0):

No, probably not.  There may well actually be no real URL of a file at all - the contents of the 'file' may well just be a load of data in a database that the server 'serves up' to look like a file.  It might also just be a file that's not available to the web server.

Unless there's some reason not to, people often overlook just asking.